# Removing the holiday from the stock chart using quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod, stock

I am trying to plot some Chinese stocks using quantmod. But the problem is that the chart always showed me the none trading day, such as the weekend and the holiday. I am wonder how to remove those days to make the chart continuous.

```
library("quantmod")

s <- getSymbols("002389.SZ",auto.assign=FALSE)   
head(s)

chartSeries(s, theme = "white", subset = "last 6 months",TA = "addSMA(n=5,col=\"gray\");addSMA(n=10,col=\"yellow\");
                addSMA(n=20,col=\"pink\");addSMA(n=30,col=\"green\");addSMA(n=60,col=\"blue\");addVo()")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's a holiday (2013-11-13 through 2014-01-27); it's either bad data, or the stock didn't trade for several days at a time (look at the volume).  If you want to only plot days when the volume is above zero, you can remove those rows before plotting.

```
x <- s[Vo(s)>0]
chartSeries(x, theme = "white", subset = "last 6 months",TA = "addSMA(n=5,col=\"gray\");addSMA(n=10,col=\"yellow\");addSMA(n=20,col=\"pink\");addSMA(n=30,col=\"green\");addSMA(n=60,col=\"blue\");addVo()")
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you remove all these days where nothing traded (or maybe it's bad data), then you're likely to draw false conclusions from any technical analysis you do.